# SQL subquery count wrong

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query to find the total counts of each employee production. When I run the query the result of outCount is wrong. I’m not really sure what I’m getting wrong. Any suggestions would be great.

```
SELECT
  r1.RegionID,
  r1.rDate,
  r1.tCount,
  r1.sCount,
  r1.outCount,
  r1.cm,
  r1.sCalc + r1.oCalc + r1.tCalc + r1.cmCalc AS dayScore,
  r1.createPID
FROM (SELECT
  q1.RegionID,
  ROUND(q1.tCount * 0.363636364, 9) AS tCalc,
  ROUND(q1.sCount * 0.181818182, 9) AS sCalc,
  ROUND(q1.outCount * 0.090909091, 9) AS oCalc,
  ROUND(q1.cm * 0.363636364, 9) AS cmCalc,
  q1.rDate,
  q1.tCount,
  q1.sCount,
  q1.outCount,
  q1.cm,
  q1.createPID
FROM (SELECT
  q1.RegionID,
  q1.rDate,
  q1.tCount,
  q1.sCount,
  q1.outCount,
  q1.cm,
  q1.createPID
FROM (SELECT
  SecurityPrincipal.RegionID,
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Ticket.dtCreate, 107) AS rDate,
  COUNT(Ticket.ticketID) AS tCount,
  COUNT(SRO.SROID) AS sCount,
  COUNT(o.NoteID) AS outCount,
  COUNT(cm.NoteID) AS cm,
  Ticket.createPID
FROM CDOC.rpt.Ticket
LEFT OUTER JOIN CDOC.rpt.SRO
  ON SRO.ticketID = Ticket.ticketID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
  Notes.NoteID,
  Notes.ticketID,
  Notes.noteCategoryID
FROM CDOC.rpt.Notes
WHERE Notes.noteCategoryID = '24') o
  ON o.ticketID = Ticket.ticketID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
  Notes.NoteID,
  Notes.ticketID
FROM CDOC.rpt.Notes
WHERE Notes.noteSubCategoryID = '13'
OR Notes.noteSubCategoryID = '16'
OR Notes.noteCategoryID = '22') cm
  ON cm.ticketID = Ticket.ticketID
INNER JOIN CDOC.rpt.SecurityPrincipal
  ON SecurityPrincipal.pid = Ticket.createPID
GROUP BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Ticket.dtCreate, 107),
         SecurityPrincipal.RegionID,
         Ticket.createPID) q1) q1) r1
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you can provide table schema, sample data, expected result and wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

This logic:

```
  COUNT(Ticket.ticketID) AS tCount,
  COUNT(SRO.SROID) AS sCount,
  COUNT(o.NoteID) AS outCount,
  COUNT(cm.NoteID) AS cm,
```

is highly suspicious.  If the ids are not null, then they will all return the same value.  Remember:  `count()` counts the number of non-NULL values.

I think you just want `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
  COUNT(DISTINCT Ticket.ticketID) AS tCount,
  COUNT(DISTINCT SRO.SROID) AS sCount,
  COUNT(DISTINCT o.NoteID) AS outCount,
  COUNT(DISTINCT cm.NoteID) AS cm,
```